# Values of checkboxes not saved in database

Tags: java, struts

I have a jsp page on which there are various checkboxes.

Some of checkboxes are disabled by default and are already selected.  There is an option to create a new template and assign values to checkboxes. These values are saved into a DB.

My problem is that saved values of selected checkboxes are always two less than values that were selected by the user.  On debugging the java code, I found that the passed values were as selected by the user.  But the values of the disabled checkboxes are saved to the DB, and the last two values selected by the user are not saved to the DB.

I am hereby attaching the code which picks the selected values and code which saves the values of checkboxes.

Code to pick selected checkbox values.

```
public ActionForward listSave(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    HardwareKey key = SecurityUtils.getKeySecurity();
    key.isFeaturePresent(HardwareKey.WS_DATA_EXCHANGE);

    DataExchangeTemplateForm thisForm = (DataExchangeTemplateForm) form;
    DataExchangeService service = (DataExchangeService) ServiceLocator
            .getServiceWithName(DataExchangeService.class.getName());
    ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();
    Integer dexTemplateId = thisForm.getTemplateId();

    String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues("isRequiredFlag");
    String[] fieldIds = request.getParameterValues("fieldId");
    String[] dataTypeIds = request
            .getParameterValues("dexDataType.dataTypeId");
    String templateType = request.getParameter("templateType");
    boolean isDexTemplate = false;

    String direction = thisForm.getDirection();
    String dexTemplateName = thisForm.getDexTemplateName();
    if (Validator.isNullOrEmpty(dexTemplateName)) {
        ActionMessage msg = new ActionMessage("error.data.exchange",
                " Template name Can't be empty");
        errors.add("error.data.exchange", msg);
        saveErrors(request, errors);
        return view(mapping, form, request, response);
    }
    String dexTemplateVersion = thisForm.getDexVersion();
    if (Validator.isNotNullGreaterThanZero(dexTemplateId)) {
        DexTemplate dexTemplateOld = (DexTemplate) service.getObject(
                DexTemplate.class, dexTemplateId);
        String profileNameOld = dexTemplateOld.getDescription();
        if (!dexTemplateName.equalsIgnoreCase(profileNameOld)
                && service.isDuplicateTemplateName(dexTemplateName)) {
            ActionMessage msg = new ActionMessage("error.data.exchange",
                    "Duplicate Template name");
            errors.add("error.data.exchange", msg);
            saveErrors(request, errors);
            return view(mapping, form, request, response);
        }

        service.updateDexTemplateAndParams(dexTemplateName, direction,
                dexTemplateId, dataTypeIds, paramValues, fieldIds,
                dexTemplateVersion);
    } else {

        if (!service.isDuplicateTemplateName(dexTemplateName)) {
            if(templateType != null && templateType.equals("extranetDex")) {
                isDexTemplate = true;
            }
            dexTemplateId = service.saveDataExchangeTemplate(
                    dexTemplateName, direction, dexTemplateVersion, isDexTemplate);
            // saving params...             
            service.saveDexTemplateParams(dexTemplateId, dataTypeIds,
                    paramValues, fieldIds);
        } else {
            ActionMessage msg = new ActionMessage("error.data.exchange",
                    "Duplicate Template name");
            errors.add("error.data.exchange", msg);
            saveErrors(request, errors);
            return view(mapping, form, request, response);
        }
    }
```

Code To Save Selected Checkbox values:

```
public void saveDexTemplateParams(Integer dexTemplateId,
        String[] dataTypeIds, String[] paramValues, String[] fieldIds)
        throws BaajaException {

    DexTemplate dexTemplate = (DexTemplate) getObject(DexTemplate.class,
            dexTemplateId);
    hibernateInitialize(dexTemplate);
    int fieldOrder = 1;
    if(paramValues!=null){
    for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
        if (!Validator.isNullOrEmpty(paramValues[i])
                && paramValues[i].equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

            DexTemplateField templatefield = new DexTemplateField();
            DexField dexField = (DexField) getObject(DexField.class,
                    Integer.parseInt(fieldIds[i]));

            templatefield.setDexField(dexField);
            templatefield.setDexTemplate(dexTemplate);
            templatefield.setFieldOrder(fieldOrder++);

            saveObject(templatefield);
        }
```

Pls Suggest any possible solution.

Comment: You can try debugging by placing debug statements in various places in the code, and you can see where the saved value is incremented twice and rectify it.

Comment: Value is not incremented anywhere in the code.I have tried by placing debugging statements.But it replaces the user selected values with values of preselected checkboxes at the time of saving.I can'nt find the statement at which this replacement takes place...

Comment: In the code given above,paramValues are values of checkboxes that were selected by the user.

Comment: Seriously, debug statements.  You'll find where it is.  Debug statements before and after you set the parameter map `templatefield`, after iBatis (or whatever it is you're using) receives the values, after it inserts into actual db.  You'll find it.  If it's not in the chain on the way there, call the Ghostbusters on your DB.  By the way, I really hope you assigned integer values to these checkboxes, because otherwise nothing about your question makes sense...

Comment: is it that even if you uncheck the checkbox it says `true` in javacode ?

Comment: no...problem is not that..problem is that it does not save all the selected values into database.and skips last two values that were selected by the user..

Answer (score 0):

Check if the name/id of the last 2 checkboxes are the same as for the other checkboxes.

It is recommended that if you are using Struts framework, use FormBean to attach to the JSP Form. In that FormBean, declare ArrayList with the name same as the property attribute of `<html:checkbox>` . This will help you minimize your support/maintenance time.